# Does quitting the game make your bloodstain disappear?

Tags: dark-souls

I haven't had to yet, but when I die and lose a ton of souls, can I quit and have them be there when I get back?

Comment: No, quitting does not make your bloodstain disappear.

Comment: why didn't you just answer the question, commenting doesn't give you any credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can exit the game, you won't lose your souls.

Dying without getting back to your bloodstain makes it disappear, though.